# how to automatically configure openvpn server?

Tags: openvpn

I was wondering the best way to get an openvpn server to configure dynamically based on the network connections of a device.

When the server is turned on I want to assume it knows nothing of the network its connected to, I have ideas but most of them involve monitoring interfaces, config editing and restarting the service which seems.

How would you do it, if you had to?

Comment: By using the operating system's network initialisation hooks to set up configuration files.

Comment: I thought that might be what someone suggests, was hoping there was a cleaner way but I did not know what I was hoping for tbh... I guess it will be a network change / interface up -> modify config file -> restart service ? this is going to require some hacky script